# Estimation of out of sample confidence interval

Tags: regression, logistic, confidence-interval, forecasting, prediction-interval

**Background**: I have estimated the following logistic function y(t) = a/(1+b*exp(c*time)), where a, b and c are the estimated coefficients, and time = 1,2,3,,,T. I want to project y into the future t = T+1, T+2, etc., i.e. I want to do an out of sample projection or forecast.

**Problem**: How can I calculate (a valid) confidence interval of the out of sample projection, for example, a 95% confidence interval? Is it sufficient to use the standard deviation of the residuals in the calculation of the interval, i.e. st.dev = square root of sum(resid^2)/T-k where k = number of estimated coefficients?